# Some uid's return an empty event array

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

Looking at this page for the Berkshire Museum: http://www.facebook.com/BerkshireMuseum/events - there is a list of events. When trying to access these events via the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) using:

```
8260447179?fields=events
```

The array is empty.

An example of a full array is doing the same thing for MASS MoCA:

```
21660976489?fields=events
```

Why would one return an empty array?

Comment: I file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/465328030218236?browse=search_51b71cbd026a79384763875